# Конкатенация числа и строки в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Может кто-нибудь объяснить почему, выражение

```
amount + '00'
```

в mysql выдаёт результат 6000, если `amount` было равно 6000.00,
а если же `amount` было равно 29250.24, то это же выражение выдаёт результат 29250.24?
Заранее благодарна!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкатенация строк в MySQL выполняется только функцией `concat`. Оператор `+` - это арифметическое сложение. При сложении строк MySQL сначала приводит их к числовому виду. А в числах не принято писать незначащие нули после запятой, вот MySQL их и отбрасывает.

При операциях над строками из за приведения типов MySQL приходится самостоятельно выбирать тип результирующих данных и разрядность после запятой, что он и делает на основании числа которое надо вывести.

При сложении заведомо числовых данных, когда приведение типа не требуется, MySQL определяет тип данных и разрядность по максимальной разрядности операндов и старается ее сохранить.

Comment: А если написать `SELECT 6000.00 + 0` то ничего не отбросится. Почему?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А ему при этом типы приводить не надо и он складывает их как числа с плавающей точкой. И видимо решает сохранить то количество разрядов которое было

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а какой правильный ответ?)